# $3$-dimensional ball of radius $\sqrt{3}$ distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions

How can I calculate the distribution of $X_1, $if $X_1$ denote the first coordinate of a point chosen at random from the $3$-dimensional ball of radius  $\sqrt{3}$?

Someone could give me some hints pls?

Comment: The probability $X_1 = x$ is the area of the cross-section at $x$ divided by the volume of the sphere.

Comment: The distance from the cross section to the end of the sphere is $r-y$ and $r=\sqrt{3}$ so we have

$$\sqrt{3}-y.$$

If $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ then

\begin{align}
y^2 = r^2 - x^2\\
y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\\
y = \sqrt{3 - x^2}\\
\end{align}
The area of a circle is determined by $\pi r^2$ so we can say the area function for a cross section that crosses the $x$-axis is

\begin{align}
A(x) = \pi \sqrt{3 - x^2}^2\\
A(x) = \pi (3 - x^2)\\
\end{align} Is it correct the area of the cross section?

Comment: Or is just $$ P(X_1=x)= \frac{A}{V}=\frac{\pi r^2}{\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}}=\frac{3}{4r} ?$$

Comment: The first one is right. $P(X = x) = \frac{A}{V} = \frac {\pi r^2}{\frac {4}{3} \pi R^3} = \frac {3-x^2}{4 \sqrt 3}$

Comment: So, the distribution is $\frac{3-x^2}{4r}$?